# How can you design a frequency divider circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, rf, frequency, clock, pll

I have been trying to design a frequency multiplier circuit which can translate frequencies from Mhz range to a few Ghz range using PLL.
But I am not able to figure out how to create the frequency divider block, as the value of the n by which it has to be divided is in the factor of 100's.

Simple divide by 2 frequencies can be done using Flip flops, but I guess cascading these in the order of 10's may not be the solution to this problem.

After looking up some more places online I have found that there were these programmable divider blocks, but I cannot figure out how these work or how to design them.

So is the programmable divider blocks the only option(if so how do you design them?) or is there any other alternative solution?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use 100s of FFs? The division ratio is exponential. With 10 FFs you divide by \$2^{10}=1024\$.?

Comment: Moreover, there are chips containing a string of FF arranged as counters, such as the old CD4060 and CD4040, that can provide ~14 division stages in one package. Of course, not that those two specific chips can handle 1GHz, but you get what I meant.

Comment: Yeah I corrected, it was a typing mistake my bad

Comment: Frequency division by a whole number is just a counter. Divide-by-2 is done by counting to 1 using a single flip-flop. Also, what context are you designing this in - FPGA? Discrete components?

Comment: No, the designing is done using using CMOS gates but not FPGA's.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a maximum frequency of ~4GHz you could cascade three of [these x4 ECL divider chips (SY10100EP33V)](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/HBW/sy10-100ep33v.pdf), by a total 4x4x4=64 division ratio. They are not programmable, so they are simple to use, just like flip-flops. Enough to bring the frequency to a more manageable ~63MHz.

Further division can then be achieved using a plain binary counter of a common logic family, like the [74HC4060](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4060.pdf) which can work safely up to ~80MHz if powered at 5V. It has an internal 14-stage counter, so it can divide by a maximum factor of 2^14=~16,000, enough to perform the division to any lower frequency you would want.

Of course you might have to design a proper interfacing circuit between those ECL chips and the HC counter: the logic levels might not be compatible by direct connection, study the datasheets carefully. Anyway the "4060" counter is a fairly common part also in other CMOS families (AC,LV, etc.), so you can search analogous parts (e.g.: 74LVC4060, 74AC4060, etc.) and see if their logic levels are better suited for direct connection with ECL outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the PLL which divides the GHz frequency from your VCO down to a more managable frequency (less than 100 MHz or so) is called a prescaler.

For the GHz frequency you need special logic which is fast enough, this is usually ECL (Emitter coupled logic) or CML (current mode logic). Actually the architecture of ECL and CML are the same, ECL is a variant of CML and if you implement it in CMOS then there are no emitters so it's called CML.

Although it is possible to build a frequency divider of for example a factor 500 using CML this is almost never done as it is very power inefficient. So what is commonly done is that only a part of the divider is in CML and the rest would be standard (CMOS) logic.

Usually these frequency dividers have a programmable division factor so that various frequencies can be made in the GHz range while the reference clock of the PLL is fixed.

This is not the place to go into more detail about this extensive topic. Fortunately plenty of excellent books have been written about RF PLLs and synthesizers. One I would recommed is "Architectures for RF Frequency Synthesizers" by Cicero Vaucher.